# Light can it behave like a magnet and help produce electricity from a copper coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-induction

Light is a electro-magnetic wave. It has varying electric and magnetic field. For me light behaves similar to the magnetic field generated by an alternating current. Physics has taught me that a copper coil in a varying magnetic field produces electricity. If this is the case, then light is composed of varying magnetic field and it should be able to produce electricity from a copper coil.

I haven't done this experiment. Has anyone done this experiment? Have you observed electricity. If you didn't observe electricity can you explain me why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To use the *magnetic field* in a light wave for induction of a current and convert it into usable power, you would have to make a copper coil smaller that the wavelength of light, which is not easy. On the other hand, the ac *electric field* of light has been used to induce currents in very small scale metal antennas (nantennas) which were rectified and utilized to generate electrical dc power. This concept of **rectennnas** is being pursued as an alternative to power generation in semiconductor solar cells.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments additional to @freecharly s answer.

You use the induction of power from electromagnetic radiation at the moment you use WLAN as well as you listen to radio. The receivers antenna rod receive polarised photons and this photons induce an AC current in the rod.

To receive remarkable energy you could use luminescent lamp and stay under a high voltage transmission line. The AC line emit EM radiation and this is enough to excite the gas inside the lamp.